# Mogrify in ImageMagick removes file name prefix when processing files

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png, mogrify

I'm using the following command to convert svg to png:

```
mogrify -path /myreal/path/to/pngdirectory -format png *.svg
```

The problem is that the file name `0102-filename.svg` becomes `filename.png`.

But I need to preserve this numbered prefix — not sure why it's not being preserved by default.

Do I miss any configuration parameter in the command to make it work?

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick are you using? Check with `mogrify -version`... For me, version `6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64` on OSX works fine and does not show the problem you describe.

Comment: There were some versions of ImageMagick that had problems with filenames beginning with numbers.  You can upgrade to the current version which should work, or you can most likely avoid the problem by renaming your input files to something like F-0102-filename.svg